# C# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8

```
        try
        {
             string directory = @"D:/user/user.txt";
             FileStream FS = new FileStream(directory, FileMode.Append);
             StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(FS);
             string register;
             register = $"{generateID()};{txtfirstName.Text};{txtLastName.Text};{txtUser.Text};{txtEmail.Text};{txtPersonalID.Text}";
             SW.WriteLine(register);
             SW.Close();
             FS.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I run this code in c# windows forms .NET framework and constanly i get the same message. I am in university and i am pretty new in programming so i have no idea what could be wrong. What are your thoughs? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: `D:.\user` ?? Did you mean `D:\user` ?

Comment: The image (please embed that directly into the question) and your code seem to disagree. In the image the "directory" is "D:\user\user.txt" in your code its "D:.\user\user.txt". The one from the code is simply an invalid path, the one from the image could (simply) not exist (and doesn't look like a directory name, but a full path "directory + filename").

Comment: i saw your message i and was like, omg i am so dumb, but nope, the error continues.
Yes, i refer to D:\user.
Its not the root directory btw

Comment: The append method creates a new files if it doesn't exists or appends it if there is one already created

Comment: Do you have permissions to that directory? try running VS Studio in administrator.

Comment: Thanks everyone! your answers were of great help, greeting from Argentina. Sorry if u didnt understand what i tried to say, English its not my mother tongue but i practice frequently though. Thanks Christian.K, your code works well on my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. First of all, you shouldn't name your variable `directory` because in the end it is a file name and used as such.

(I'll ignore the difference between the image "D:\user\user.txt" and the code "D.:\user\user.txt" and will assume you actually ment and did use the first).

Most likely, the `D:\User` directory does not exist and the `FileStream` class will not create it for you. It will simply assume that all (sub) directories up to the specified file name exist and fail otherwise.

So make sure that the directory exists, either outside your application, or like so:

```
string fileName = @"D:\user\user.txt";
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}
FileStream FS = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append);

// ... rest of code
```

Comment: I think you can even skip the `Directory.Exists()` call. According to Microsofts doc the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` method does this check anyway. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-6.0

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

Comment: @Christian-K:  Late comment, but I need to fully qualify Path:   System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);  // otherwise very excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are running the application on a windows machine. In windows, the file path needs to be given like
string directory = @"D:\user\user.txt";
Also, make sure this file path exists and the application you are running has permission to write on this file.
If you are running a test application then give permission as FullControl to Everyone. AS below

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you are sure about the path, check if you run VS as an administrator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).